# How to get a value of id attribute in <s:textfield /> in Struts 2 action?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a `textfield` like this:

```
<s:textfield id="123456" name="abc" value="cateory name" />
```

It is possible to get the **value of `id` attribute** in Struts2 Action class (which is `123456`)?

Comment: Because I need that id value to perform database query. otherwise, I have to use another hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OO (Object Oriented) programming, you should define a Category class, with id and name fields, and related accessor methods, like this:

```
public class Category{
   private long id;
   private String name;

   public String getName(){
      return this.name;
   }
   public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }

   public long getId(){
      return this.id;
   }
   public void setId(Long id){
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

Then point to them with hidden or visible fields, according to your needs.

In your case, ID should be an hidden field:

```
<s:hidden name="category.id" value="123456" />
<s:textfield name="category.name" value="blabla" />
```

you could even iterate a list of categories, like this:

```
<s:iterator name="categories" var="cat" status="ctr">
   <s:hidden name="#cat[#ctr.index].id" value="123456" />
   <s:textfield name="#cat[#ctr.index].name" value="blabla" />
</s:iterator>
```

and post them back into the ArrayList of the target Action automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery("input[name='abc']").attr("id");
```